# Install Linux on Chromebook for wireless security testing?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark, monitoring

I’m envisioning myself walking around my home with a small laptop in one hand, and a smartphone in the other hand.  The laptop would have wireless security software (WireShark, maybe nzyme or similar) running on Linux.  The smartphone would be video recording both the laptop’s screen and the immediate surroundings.  The idea is to document where decibel measurements suggest is the origin of inappropriate wireless signals, if I find any created by roommates or neighbors.

I’m attracted to using a Chromebook because they are small, and because the ones beyond Google’s “End Of Life” are very inexpensive.  I want to spend as little as possible on such a speculative project; I’m unsure whether I will encounter a threat.  I currently have no other reason to buy a laptop or another Linux computer, but there is one Android app I might try running, so I will keep the ChromeOS and have dual booting.

The problem:  I don’t know how to verify whether Chromebook wifi hardware can be put into the monitoring mode required by WireShark and maybe by other software.  How do I discover that, short of buying the hardware and trying to install?

What experiences with security software on old Chromebooks can you share with everyone reading this?

Is there a different ultra-cheap approach?

Thanks to the responders here on StackExchange!

Comment: This is a pretty broad and lengthy question when all you want to know is if a Chromebook can be used in monitor mode. And that's not even a security question (and easily looked up: https://www.google.com/search?q=chromebook+wifi+monitor+mode). As for "please share your experiences", we are a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so such questions are off-topic.